# Trouble synchronizing generic TList and TListBox

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have trouble keeping a TListbox in sync with a TList. Each time an item is added to a generic TList, OnNotify is called and the callback calls just one procedure: `create_gradients`. Its code is below:

```
  procedure TColor_Dialog.create_gradients;
  var Editor: TGradient_Editor;
      eGradient: Int32;
      y: single;
      s: string;
  begin
     List_Names.Clear;
     List_Gradients.Clear;

     for eGradient := 0 to FColor_Editor.nGradients - 1 do
     begin
        List_Names.Items.Add (FColor_Editor [eGradient].Check_Rainbow.Text);
     end; // for

     List_Gradients.BeginUpdate;
     try
        for eGradient := 0 to FColor_Editor.nGradients - 1 do
        begin
           Editor := FColor_Editor [eGradient];
           y := (eGradient + 1) * Editor.Height;
           Editor.Position.Y := y;
           s := Editor.Check_Rainbow.Text;
           List_Gradients.AddObject (Editor);
        end; // for
     finally
        List_Gradients.EndUpdate;
     end; // try..finally
  end; // create_gradients //
```

As you see it simply enumerates all items in the list. Each item in the list is a `TGradient_Editor` which in turn has `TFrame` as a parent. On the parent are some FMX controls as combolorboxes, an image and a checkbox (Check_Rainbow). `Check_Rainbow.Text` is used for identification  purposes. When the gradient editor is created, it creates a unique name from `frame_%s` where %s is a sequence number that is incremented each time a gradient editor is created. `Owner` and `Parent` are both `List_Gradients`.

[image]

From the image above you can see what happens. the listbox on the right is added for checking and just shows the text's, which is the correct sequence by the way. When I use the debugger to follow the addition of the gradient editors to `List_Gradient` they are processed in the same order. But the order of the gradient editors is **wrong**. I have to mention that the aligment of the gradient editors is alTop. I added even some code to ensure that the editor is Positioned at the very bottom of the `List_Gradients`.

I appear not to understand something. I cannot imagine that sequential adding to a `TListBox` cannot result in the correct order. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's going to be related to `alTop`. You'll probably need to set the `Top` to `BottomItem.Top+BottomItem.Height` before you add.

Comment: That's what I tried to remedy with the `y := (eGradient + 1) * Editor.Height; Editor.Position.Y := y`, so the item is added at he bottom. And that does not work. Does BottomItem really exist, if so is it VCL? Forgot to mention this is FMX, changed it now.

Comment: BottomItem is shorthand. You have to work out how to implement it!

Comment: Please can you move the code from your update into an answer. It's better to keep questions and answers separate.

Comment: @David, thanks for the hint. I've done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
procedure TColor_Dialog.create_gradients;
var
  Editor: TGradient_Editor;
  eGradient: Int32;
  y: single;
begin
  List_Names.Clear;
  List_Gradients.Clear;

  for eGradient := 0 to FColor_Editor.nGradients - 1 do
  begin
    List_Names.Items.Add (FColor_Editor[eGradient].Check_Rainbow.Text);
  end;

  List_Gradients.BeginUpdate;
  try
    y := 0.0; // or whatever value you want to start at...
    for eGradient := 0 to FColor_Editor.nGradients - 1 do
    begin
      Editor := FColor_Editor[eGradient];
      Editor.Position.Y := y;
      List_Gradients.AddObject(Editor);
      y := y + Editor.Height;
    end;
  finally
    List_Gradients.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This does not work either, however, your and Davids remarks set me to investigate into the right direction. The key issue is this: `AddObject` does not add an Object at the end of the list so one is tempted to use `Align := alTop`. That causes all the trouble listed here. Your solution works when I switch off the `alTop` aligment. When doing that another annoyment starts, that of overlapping objects. And that is where your code comes in handy. One has to add that the width of the added object should be equal to that of its Parents `TListBox`. See update.

Answer (score 3):

As requested I moved the answer to this section. The correct code is:

```
  procedure TColor_Dialog.create_gradients;
  var Editor: TGradient_Editor;
      eGradient: Int32;
      y: single;
  begin
     List_Gradients.BeginUpdate;
     try
        List_Gradients.Clear;
        y := 0;
        for eGradient := 0 to FColor_Editor.nGradients - 1 do
        begin
           Editor := FColor_Editor [eGradient];
           Editor.Position.X := 0;
           Editor.Position.Y := y;
           Editor.Width := List_Gradients.Width;
           List_Gradients.AddObject (Editor);
           y := y + Editor.Height;
        end; // for
     finally
        List_Gradients.EndUpdate;
     end; // try..finally
  end; // create_gradients //
```

and not using any alignment anymore. Adding Objects to a `TListBox` is a real nice feature of FMX. However, be prepared that things sometimes work differently than you expect. For one thing: objects are not positioned in the same way as strings.