# Error in adding objects to a TListBox?

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-xe5

An apparently attractive feature of FMX is adding visual objects to a TListBox. In a previous question I mentioned the trouble of [correctly positioning objects inside the TListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960267/trouble-synchronizing-generic-tlist-and-tlistbox/19998855#19998855). An additional annoyance I discovered is using InsertObject. When 8 objects are added to a TListBox I get "Argument out of range". On Android I can get this error message when adding the 2nd object. I could isolate this problem in a small program:

```
  unit tlist_item;

  interface

  uses
    System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
    FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls;

  type
     TItem_Frame = class(TFrame)
      Button1: TButton;
      Label1: TLabel;
      SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;

      procedure SpeedButton1Click (Sender: TObject);

     public
        FOnInsert: TNotifyEvent;
        class var FSequence: Int32;

        constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent); override;
     end; // Class: TFrame1 //

  implementation

  {$R *.fmx}

  constructor TItem_Frame.Create (AOwner: TComponent);
  begin
     inherited Create (AOwner);

     Self.Name := Format ('Frame_%d', [FSequence]);
     FSequence := FSequence + 1;
  end; // Create //

  procedure TItem_Frame.SpeedButton1Click (Sender: TObject);
  begin
     if Assigned (FOnInsert)
        then FOnInsert (Sender);
  end;

  end.
```

The code above describes a TFrame with three components. By pressing the speed button an object is added to the listbox in the main program as follows:

```
  unit tlist_main;

  interface

  uses
     System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
     FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts,
     FMX.ListBox,
     tlist_item;

  type
     TMain_Form = class(TForm)
      ListBox: TListBox;
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

     private
        procedure do_insert (Sender: TObject);

     public

     end; // Class: TForm1 //

  var
    Main_Form: TMain_Form;

  implementation

  {$R *.fmx}

  procedure TMain_Form.FormCreate (Sender: TObject);
  begin
     do_insert (ListBox);
  end; // FormCreate //

  procedure TMain_Form.do_insert (Sender: TObject);
  var
     frame: TItem_Frame;
  begin
     frame := TItem_Frame.Create (ListBox);
     frame.Parent := ListBox;
     frame.Position.Y := frame.FSequence * frame.Height;
     frame.Width := ListBox.Width;
     frame.FOnInsert := do_insert;
     ListBox.InsertObject (frame.FSequence - 1, frame);
  end; // do_insert //

  end.
```

The error occurs in do_insert at the InsertObject call and happen both at Win32 and Android. I wonder whether this is a bug or an error of mine. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Interesting. Also, your second question should be asked in another question.

Comment: I adapted the question to your suggestion and mentioned the platforms: the error occurs both on Win32 and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
procedure TMain_Form.do_insert (Sender: TObject);
  var
     frame: TItem_Frame;
  begin
     frame := TItem_Frame.Create (ListBox);
     frame.Parent := ListBox;
     frame.align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
     frame.Height := 50;
     frame.FOnInsert := do_insert;
     ListBox.InsertObject (frame.FSequence - 1, frame);
  end;
```

or check out this link how to make custom ListBox items:
[Create custom Listbox item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837752/2728408)